# Limit in $D'(R)$ of an odd function

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $f$ be odd real locally integrable function such that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xf(x)=1$$

I need to show that $g_{\varepsilon}(x)=\varepsilon^{2}f'(\varepsilon x)$ has limit in sense of distributions and find the limit. First we get this:$$\left<g_{\varepsilon},\varphi\right>=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\varepsilon^{2}f'(\varepsilon x)\varphi(x) \, dx=\varepsilon\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\varepsilon f'(\varepsilon x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx=-\varepsilon\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(\varepsilon x) \, \varphi'(x) \, dx$$ with last equality provided by partial integration. I pretty much don't know how to proceed from here (because another p.i. brings me back to the beggining) so I'd be glad if someone can offer any hint.

Edit: if $f$ is odd, does it mean that $f'$ is even?

Comment: If $f$ is odd by taking the derivative of $f(x)=-f(-x)$ (in the sense of distributions for example) one obtain $f'(x)=f'(-x)$.

Comment: Perhaps a substitution $y = \varepsilon x$?